# How to set target Android SDK version and iOS version when using EAS with Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have been looking high and low for an answer to this question but i cannot seem to find anything.

In my Expo project i want to be able to set up the target versions for each platform. Right now i have a physical android that is running android version 12, but my project is only compatible with version 13 so i can't download it from the Play Store.
And on iOS i don't want the same thing to happen where it won't be able to be downloaded on older iPhones.
I have already tried ejecting it which gives me the android folder and i can change the SDK version there. But i am not able to get the ios folder which i need because i don't have a Mac.

Is there a way i can set this up without ejecting my project to bare React Native?
Any answers are very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add expo-build-properties, check the docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/